# Borel algebra , linear , supremun.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, calculus-of-variations

Let $K$ is compact metric space. $B(K)$ is a $\sigma$-Borel algebra in $K$. Let $\mu$ is a positive measure on $K$. $\mu(K)=1$. Let $X$ is a Banach space.

Let: $G:K\times X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, G(t,e)$. Assume:

$+ $ $G(.,e)$ is continuous  $\forall e\in X$.

$+ $ $G(t,.)$ is linear and continuous  $\forall t\in K$.

Prove that :

$$\sup_{e\in X,||e||\leq 1}\int_{K}G(t,e)d\mu(t)=\int_{K}\sup_{e\in X,||e||\leq 1}G(t,e)d\mu(t)=\int_{K}||G(t,.)||_{L(X,\mathbb{R})}d\mu(t)$$

Comment: It feels like the Monotone Convergence Theorem could be either directly used or adapted to this case, Because of linearity we have $\sup_e G(t, e) \geq 0$ for all $t$.

Comment: Yeah ! The difficult is to choose the sequence !